# Getting HTTP status 400-Bad Request REST

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot

I have created a project and getting BAD request error

Below are the code snippet, apart from this i have more code in file which i dont think making any trouble.

```
@Controller
public class RESTController{

@RequestMapping(value="testing", method=Request method.GET)
Public @ResponseBody String TestingXml(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Test test){
String welcome=test.getName();
return welcome;
}

}

Castor-mapping.xml
<class name="abc.def.model.Test">
<field name="name" type="string">
<bind-xml name="name"/>
</field>
</class>
```

This above code is inside mapping tag

And have written the Test.java with single field as name and getter setter.

Can any one please help
Ignore the typo as writting all this from mobile, getting no error in eclipse, while creating war and deploying it over tomcat getting the bad request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET` HTTP method doesn't support passing a request body.

You need either to use `@RequestParam` with primitive field (from your example it is `name`), or change request method to `POST/PATCH/PUT/DELETE`.

Based on your example, usage of `@RequestParam`:

```
@Controller
public class RESTController{

    @RequestMapping(value="testing", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String TestingXml(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String welcome){
        return welcome;
    }

}
```

You can pass it like this: `http://localhost:8080/api?welcome=Hi`

You can read about its usage [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param).